# All the perfect numbers between 1 and 500 program algorithm says it works but it doesn't

Tags: java, algorithm

I am writing a program to tell me all the perfect numbers between 1 and 500 and I made this program, but it doesn't work although the algorithm makes sense.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class allPerfect {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("All perfect numbers between 1 and 500 are:");
        for (int j = 0; j != 501; j++) {

            for (int i = 1; i < j; i++) {
                if (j % i == 0) {

                    sum = sum + i;
                    if (sum == j) {
                        System.out.println(j);
                        sum = 0;
                    } else {
                        sum = 0;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you only check for (sum==j) after looping over all i?

Comment: Define "doesn't work" - we're not mind-readers!

Comment: @TobySpeight There's only three perfect numbers less than 500.  I would assume "doesn't work" means that it prints something other than those 3.  My complaint would be the title "algorithm says it works".

Comment: Please structure your question so that it makes sense grammatically.

Comment: I think it wrong not to include the definition used of a term like `perfect number` in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the comment in-line.

```
class allPerfect {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    int sum;
    System.out.println("All perfect numbers between 1 and 500 are:");
    for(int j = 1; j!=501; j++){
      sum = 0;     //**You should reset the sum at the start of the inner loop.**
      for(int i = 1; i < j; i++ ){
        if(j % i == 0) {
          sum = sum + i;
        }
      }      
      if(sum == j) {              //------ statement-1
        System.out.println(j);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`statement-1` you check the sum of all the divisor is equal to the number, after summing up for all the numbers less than `j`.

**You can ignore all the odd number `(j)` in outer loop, because odd perfect number does not exist. To be precise: it is not known that odd perfect number exists.**

Comment: You should also move the final if out one level (i.e. after you've summed all the factors). Currently, if a subset of factors sum to the number being tested then it'll think it has a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting sum before you finish finding all of a numbers divisors.

```
 for(int i = 1; i < j; i++ ){
        if(j % i == 0){

            sum = sum + i;
            if(sum == j){
                System.out.println(j);
                sum = 0;
            }else{

                sum = 0;
            }
        } 
    }
```

You should do the if(sum == j) only after you exit the inner for loop.

Comment: Alternatively, just remove the sum = 0; from the else statement.

Comment: If you did that, it would probably fail on some amicable numbers.